# Where do diskmgmt or diskpart store the state of dynamic disks?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart, dynamic-disk

I have physically equivalent machines that are near exact clones of each other. Their `C:` drive gets replicated from a master machine using `rsync` under Linux, with a few files and registry entries that are deliberately preserved. This works very well.

The only problem I am facing is with dynamic (in my case, spanned) disks. When machine `Alice` is replicated on machine `Bob`, only `C:` gets replicated, but if `Bob` has a dynamic disk called `D:`, it will disappear when `Bob` reboots. I can then manually put `D:` online using `diskpart`, but I’d like to avoid this if possible.

I suppose the state of `D:` is stored somewhere in the registry; I would just need to preserve these specific keys. But I have been unable to find where `diskmgmt` / `diskpart` store the dynamic disk configuration. Where should I look? Or can someone maybe suggest a tool to find the information by myself?

Comment: Dynamic disk state is stored in a reserved part of the disk itself, not the registry.

Comment: @LMiller7 that is true of the layout configuration, but whether a dynamic disk is *e.g.* online or foreign is definitely stored on the system, not on the disk itself.